# Chromium doesn't work

Tags: troubleshooting, browser, chromium, dropbox

My chromium browser doesn't work for some reason. What I mean by that is that it doesn't even start up when I click on chromium icon or choose chromium from applications menu. What might be the problem?

After typing: `chromium-browser` in the terminal I get this:

```
/home/freshnrg/.themes/T-ish-Brushed-Overlaid/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:56: Clearlooks configuration option "sunkenmenu" is not supported and will be ignored.
/home/freshnrg/.themes/T-ish-Brushed-Overlaid/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:57: Clearlooks configuration option "menuitemstyle" is not supported and will be ignored.
/home/freshnrg/.themes/T-ish-Brushed-Overlaid/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:58: Clearlooks configuration option "listviewitemstyle" is not supported and will be ignored.
/home/freshnrg/.themes/T-ish-Brushed-Overlaid/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:59: Clearlooks configuration option "progressbarstyle" is not supported and will be ignored.
Segmentation fault
```

So nothing about any errors connected to chromium because all that is just my ubuntu theme errors witch i get all the time. don't understand that **Segmentation fault** not sure if that has anything to do with chromium.

after typing: `rm -rf ~/.config/chromium`
and then: `chromium-browser`

`chromium` actually starts from scratch asking if I want to import bookmarks from firefox and it doesn't matter what I choose because that is it. After that nothing happens and chromium still doesn't work.

Re-installation didn't helped. I still get segmentation fault error.

EDIT: I've done all this, went back to official version 5.0.375.127, I've re-installed it couple of times and still nothing. I still have that segmentation fault error.

EDIT: It's definitely something to do with dropbox. After installing dropbox on my new account Chromium stopped working. How can I get rid of dropbox on my old account as I've uninstalled it and deleted all the files that has anything to do with dropbox but I still can't get Chromium to work?

Comment: Try opening a terminal and typing `chromium-browser` and pressing enter to see if it gives any error messages.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing `chromium-browser`?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: that's "chromium-browser", not just "chromium". "chromium" is a dummy package that actually links to "chromium-bsu", a shoot-em-up game :)

Comment: @Jawa: one of the best shoot-em-ups for linux! ;D

Comment: @Marco: YES ! :-p
@Freshnrg: I edited my answer.

Comment: What happens when you type `google-chrome`?

Comment: You can safely ignore the theme errors.  Those are common and usually harmless.

Comment: A segmentation fault happens when a process accesses memory incorrectly, FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild shot: Do you have the new Ubuntu font beta installed?.

There are a couple of reports on the net that this font crashes Chrome: [upstream bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51243), [ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/623868).

Comment: cheers mate this is it! it works fine now.

Comment: I just read that on WebUpd8[1] and was going to post the answer here [1] http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/webupd8/~3/TiIP7upyhlg/new-way-to-get-new-official-ubuntu-font.html

Answer (score 2):

I had something like this a very, very long time ago. I wonder where you're getting chromium from.

`5.0.375.125~r53311` seems to be the latest official version (there is a slightly newer `proposed` version) but the current chromium-daily PPA is at `7.0.512.0...`. I'm always slightlt dubious of people who suggest just blindly upgrading things but in this case it might help you get it working.

To install the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
update-manager
```

Then just install the updates. You'll get a lot of updates through this and it's quite likely you might find something breaks as this is bleeding-edge software.

If you find it doesn't work or something else breaks, you can go back to stock versions with `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge chromium-browser
```

Comment: And remember: Just because it's the chromium-daily ppa, doesn't mean they don't offer stable, dev, and beta build of chromium, because they do!  All are listed @ https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/

Comment: Yup, good point. They are all different versions. `-stable` is only a couple of builds newer than the repo version, `-beta` is v6.* while `-dev` and `-daily` are v7.*

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what build you are running (beta, dev, daily or stable). The instructions I am providing you with will move you to the stable build.

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
```

This will purge Chromium. Now to remove other relate files

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chromium-daily-[build]-lucid.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chromium-daily-[build]-lucid.list.save
```

This removes the PPA for the build you are using. Replace [build] with the build you are using. Tab completion can help.

```
rm -rfv ~/.config/chromium/
```

This will remove the you Chromium settings.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable
```

This will ad the stable PPA.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will refresh the list of packages.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

This install the stable version Chromium. If this doesn't work try changing your theme. The terminal output mentions you theme.

Comment: I've done all this and even changed my theme but still nothing. What is that: segmentation fault? I remember using Chromium and it worked but suddenly is doesn't. I don't remember what I did as it stopped working few days ago and I was using firefox but it's just too slow in comparison to Chromium that's why I want it back.

Comment: You could try clearing you cache (~/.cache/chromium/). If doing all that doesn't work, try creating a new user (not a "Guest Session" it won't run do to a bug) and running Chromium via that user. A Segmentation Fault is caused by a memory violation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Comment: yeah it does work on new user account. but it's a bit pointless to creating it just for Chromium. will have to figure this out somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching it from the commandline: open a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal) and type: `chromium-browser`.

If it launches, then you have a problem in your shortcut (very unlikely). You can edit it from System->Preferences->Main menu.

If it doesn't launch, you should get some error message displayed that should explain why it failed. If you can't fix it yourself based on that, please copy those messages to your original post, so that we can try helping you :)

In any case, you can try removing your local settings for it (under your HOME folder, delete the .config/chromium folder) so that it is restarted clean next time (as if you just installed it). Now be cautious: this will delete all your settings, including bookmarks...

To do that, under a terminal, type:
`rm -rf ~/.config/chromium`

EDIT: the "Segmentation fault" is actually very interesting: it tells that Chromium crashed in an ugly fashion (not because of a handled error, but because it tried to do something wrong on the system).
Either it is an issue with the installation, or with a plugin that you added to it...
I think you should completely uninstall it, and reinstall it again, just to see if it solves the issue.