# Chromium doesn't open anymore

Tags: chromium, browser

My Chromium browser doesn't work. It doesn't even start up. 
Typing `chromium-browser` in the terminal I get this error:

```
[18118:18118:5103105507:FATAL:profile_impl.cc(315)] Failed to create /home/nicholas/.cache/chromium/Default
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Reinstallation doesn't fix the problem. I tried to follow steps in [Chromium doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3424/chromium-doesnt-work), but without success. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that your home drive is not full?

Comment: tried `rm /home/nicholas/.cache/chromium -rf` ?

Comment: Reinstalling an app such as Chromium or Firefox will not help in most cases, unless you also totally uninstall it first, removing the settings file with your profile from your home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sudo mkdir -p /home/nicholas/.cache/chromium/Default
>   
>  sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/nicholas/.cache/chromium/Default

Comment: If he is nicholas, then there is no reason to use sudo, and no reason to change the owner, since he is the owner automatically.

Comment: @MartyFried just in case.
And, I solved a similar problem with chown.

Comment: You mean, just in case he is not nicholas?  If he is, and he is not the owner of his home directory, then he has more serious problems than this.

Comment: Thank you, @TheGatorate, you're awesome! :D (sorry, can't thumbs up your answer yet, but when I earn reputation I'll do!)
Thanks to all others that answear too!

Comment: @TheGatorade , the problem now is that Chromium isn't visible in Alt + Tab. What could I do to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: @nicholascamp If i've been helpful, click on the tick on the left of the answer, so you'll accept that as your answer.

Comment: @TheGatorade I don't have 15 points of reputation yet, but when I do I will vote your answear as useful.

Comment: @nicholascamp Why you don't just accept as answer? You can do also with 1 rep. It's the symbol under the "Vote down" arrow. :) You also get 2 reputation for doing this.

Comment: @TheGatorade done! :)